# Solution for user account activation?

Tags: 6, users

By some chance would a module exist for this registration / user activation workflow?

I'm looking for a module the following functionality:

1. Each user when registering has a dropdown to select their sales representative
2. The sales rep will then get an email regarding this user's registration
3. Since this sales rep knows that they're a user they'll approve this user quicker than a single administrator

Essentially, the user has the ability then to delegate who approves their account improving account approval efficiency (the goal).

Also, could this functionality be accomplished with rules somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is three modules.

http://drupal.org/project/token_profile

and enabling the core module profile.

Add any custom fields for a sales rep. Then enable rules. Rules will take any tokenized field based on certain events.